# How can I check if the time is more than an hour later?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a database entry that update the date/time in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

Now I want to check, if there is a space inbetween the the database and the actual time from 60 minutes. How can I do that?

Example:

```
DB: 2020-02-14 10:00:00
Time now: 2020-02-14 11:01:00
Do something

DB: 2020-02-14 10:00:00
Time now: 2020-02-14 10:59:00
Do nothing
```

Comment: Which database are you using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...? Please add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: Are you looking for PHP solution or SQL?

Comment: MySQL with type: timestamp Would more likely do it with php but would take both suggestions if the result is the same

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$t1 = strtotime( '2006-04-14 11:30:00' );
$t2 = strtotime( '2006-04-12 12:30:00' );
$diff = round(($t1 - $t2) / 3600);
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can do date arithmetics:

```
update mytable
set mydatetime = now()
where mydatetime <= now() - interval 1 hour and id = ?
```

The `where` clause filters on record whose column `mydatetime`is more than one hour old. You did not tell what you want to do , so I assumed an update query, that resets the date/time to the current date/time.

This assumes that you want to update the timestamp *of a given record*, not accross the whole table, hence condition `id = ?`, which you can adapt - or remove - for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Schmaniel at first i think you should use Carbon()
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ to get the right results. It's a great way to work with timeformats and timestamps.

```html
$now = Carbon::now();
$dbtime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1975-05-21 22:10:22');

$totalDuration = $now->diffForHumans($dbtime);
dd($totalDuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$currentDate = new DateTime();
$databaseDate = new DateTime($dateFromDatabase);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

Then you can check using the $interval variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) like this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');
```

you can use one of the follwing units:

> MICROSECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH,
>   QUARTER, or YEAR.